# Sorting list using two criteria - objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

I need some help, I'm trying to do some object list sorting in Objective-c.

In the object I have two properties: NSDate: date, String priority (which receives numbers from 1 to 3).

I need to order the list using these two parameters as criteria.
I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Can you add more info, some code that you have tried out and what difficulties did you face?

Comment: What have you tried? Your sort seems quite basic, but what's the logic behind the sort? What's the primary sort? By date or by string priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSSortDescriptor` to compound sorting criterias e.g.:

```objectivec
@interface Item : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *priority;

@end

@implementation Item

- (instancetype)initWithDate:(NSDate *)date priority:(NSString *)priority {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.date = date;
        self.priority = priority;
    }
    return self;
}

@end

...

NSDate *date = [NSDate new];
NSArray *items = @[
    [[Item alloc] initWithDate:date priority:@"1"],
    [[Item alloc] initWithDate:date priority:@"0"],
    [[Item alloc] initWithDate:date priority:@"3"],
    [[Item alloc] initWithDate:date priority:@"2"],
];

NSSortDescriptor* sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor* sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"priority" ascending:YES];
    
NSArray *sorted = [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort1, sort2]];
```